# Obtained incorrect standard deviation and mean values with moving rectangle in VB2010

Tags: vb.net, image-processing

I have an  grayscale image, I have been a able to display a rectangle on the image to extract the ROI and compute the standard deviation and mean. However, when I'm moving the rectangle around, i notice I have the wrong values for the image, especially where the image is entirely black. At this area, i should be getting a zero for the mean and standard deviation. However, im obtaining a 0 for the mean and negative values for the standard deviation and other point of this black area the mean increases to the mean the same as light dominated areas. I have been struggling to come up with a solution. Are there any ideas to help. I'll be grateful. My code for the mousemove button and mean and standard deviation are posted below. Thanks.

```
Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseDown

    Dim mean As Double = 0
    Dim meancount As Integer = 0
    Dim bmap As New Bitmap(400, 400)
    bmap = PictureBox1.Image
    Dim colorpixel As Color = bmap.GetPixel(e.X, e.Y)
    '   Dim pixels As Double = colorpixel.R + colorpixel.G + colorpixel.B
    If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left AndAlso Rect.Contains(e.Location) Then
        If (PictureBox1.Image Is Nothing) Or (PictureBox1.Height - (e.Y + SquareHeight) < 0) Or (PictureBox1.Width - (e.X + SquareWidth) < 0) Then
        Else
            Dim ROI As New Bitmap(400, 400)
            Dim x As Integer = 0
            Dim countx As Integer = 0
            Dim county As Integer = 0

            For i = e.X To (e.X + SquareWidth)
                For j = (e.Y + x) To (e.Y + SquareHeight)
                    Dim pixelcolor As Color = bmap.GetPixel(i, j)
                    ROI.SetPixel(countx, county, pixelcolor)
                    mean = mean + pixelcolor.R + pixelcolor.G + pixelcolor.B
                    county += 1
                    meancount += 1
                Next
                county = 0
                countx += 1
                x = x + 1
            Next

            mean = mean / meancount
            Dim SD = mean - 75
            Dim area As Integer = (SquareHeight * SquareWidth)
            Dim anotherForm As Form2
            anotherForm = New Form2(mean, SD, area, 34)
            anotherForm.Show()
        End If
    End If

    '   Catch ex As Exception
    '   MessageBox.Show(ex.Message())
    '  End Try
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseMove(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseMove
    Rect.X = e.X + x
    Rect.Y = e.Y + y
    Rect.Width = SquareWidth
    Rect.Height = SquareHeight
    ' Label1.Text = "XRect: " + Rect.X.ToString() + " YRect: " + Rect.Y.ToString() + " Xmouse " + e.X.ToString() + " Ymouse " + e.Y.ToString()
    PictureBox1.Refresh()
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox1_Paint(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Paint
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, Rect)
End Sub

Private Function StandardDeviation(ByVal image As Bitmap, ByVal mean As Double, ByVal meancount As Integer) As Double
    Dim SD(SquareHeight * SquareWidth) As Double
    Dim count As Integer = 0
    For i = 0 To SquareWidth
        For j = 0 To SquareHeight
            Dim pixelcolor As Color = image.GetPixel(i, j)

            SD(count) = Double.Parse(pixelcolor.R) + Double.Parse(pixelcolor.G) + Double.Parse(pixelcolor.B) - mean
            count += 1
        Next
    Next

    Dim SDsum As Double = 0
    For i = 0 To count
        SDsum = SDsum + SD(i)
    Next

    SDsum = SDsum / (SquareHeight * SquareWidth)

    SDsum = ((SDsum) ^ (1 / 2))
    Return SDsum

End Function

Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseClick
    Dim P As Point = e.Location
    P = New Point
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You should calc mean like
`mean = mean / (meancount * 3)` (there is 3 colors added) and it is better to calc running mean instead of summing all and divide later. I guess there can be more math errors.

Comment: I tried it the results for the mean improved, but its off somewhat. However, I'd like to ask a question. Given my standard deviation function how do i pass that to the the newform it seems if i can pass the standard deviation function into that my standard deviation values will be correct                                           mean = mean / meancount
            Dim SD = mean - 75
            Dim area As Integer = (SquareHeight * SquareWidth)
            Dim anotherForm As Form2
            anotherForm = New Form2(mean, SD, area, 34)
            anotherForm.Show()